# How do I toggle a classname to a component via an action in another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm very new to react about a day in so I apologize if this is a silly question,

I'm trying to toggle a classname for css styling to a div when a button is pressed, the button is a separate component in the page and I'm not sure how I can connect the two Originally with using jquery I had something like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var header = $('header'),
           btn = $('button.toggle-nav');

       btn.on('click', function() {
           header.toggleClass('active');
       });
   });
}
```

But i realized it wasn't running on the first load of the page. All help would be very much appreciated!

I've taken out the button component and I have something like this now,

```
<header className="contain active">

  <Navigation/>

  <button className="toggle-nav">
      <span className="fa fa-bookmark-o" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </button>

  <div className="divider"></div>
```

To clarify I'm trying to get the button to toggle the "active" classname for the header

Comment: Try something in React without using jQuery and let us know what errors you face.

Comment: Could you please post your complete app.js?

Comment: Mixing the Virtual DOM (React) and something that manipulates the DOM directly (jQuery) is not advisable.

Comment: Yeah I kinda figured, I'm wondering if I could reproduce what the jquery function does ( toggleing the classname) in the "proper" react way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to hold the knowledge of whether the header is active or not in state. It would look something like this.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args)
    this.state = { active: false }
    this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this)
  }

  onButtonClick() {
    this.setState((state) => ({ active: !state.active }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <header className={`contain ${this.state.active ? 'active' : ''}`>
        <Navigation/>
        <button className="toggle-nav" onClick={this.onButtonClick}>
          <span className="fa fa-bookmark-o" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="divider"></div>
      </>
    )

  }
}
```

The button is passed an onClick callback, which toggles the active state. The component is re-rendered as a result of the state change, and the active class name is rendered conditionally, based on the state value.